# Haxe - Objects on stage not displaying when deploying to windows

Tags: windows, object, haxe, stage, nme

I am using Haxe/nme with Flash Develope to port a flash game to multiple platforms. All my imported library's are from NME. The program compiles and runs fine with Flash as the target. But when I target Windows the program compiles and runs, even the music starts playing, but all I see is a blank window.

All objects on the stage are missing. There are no errors and everything seems to compile/run perfectly, except for no objects showing up?

Is there something special I need to do to make objects show up with a windows target?

Comment: Try to build simple application with one sprite/object on stage and test it. If sprite will not shown again, put this example on the web and we will try to investigate.

Comment: Also what version of NME you use? And what is an objects you add to stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "make objects show up on windows target" setting. Its very hard to tell you if there is something wrong with your code without seeing it.

Please try to compile the example project to windows to see a working project. http://www.nme.io/developer/documentation/getting-started/

Answer (score 3):

I solved it. Interlaced PNG's work's just fine when deploying to flash but will show absolutely nothing on windows with no errors at all. This is clearly something that should be put in big bold letters somewhere to warn newcomers, but now that I know everything is running great.

Comment: Nice find, apparently there is also a performance cost when using them if you can avoid them, in the comments they talk about a fix being done https://haxenme.atlassian.net/browse/NME-256